# Cannot connect to Elasticsearch from Go server running in Docker

Tags: docker, go, elasticsearch, kibana

I have set up an environment today that runs a `golang:1.13-alpine` image, along with the latest images for Elasticsearch and Kibana.

Elasticsearch and Kibana are running fine when accessing from my local machine, but I cannot connect to Elasticsearch through the Go server. I have put this together from guides I have found and followed.

I am still a bit green using Docker. I have an idea that I am pointing at the wrong ip address in the container, but I am unsure how to fix it. Hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    image: go-docker-webserver
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.2
    environment:
      node.name: elasticsearch
      cluster.initial_master_nodes: elasticsearch
      cluster.name: docker-cluster
      bootstrap.memory_lock: "true"
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.4.2
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
```

**Dockefile:**

```
FROM golang:1.13-alpine as builder

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    bash \
    gcc \
    git \
    musl-dev

RUN mkdir build
COPY . /build
WORKDIR /build

RUN go get
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o webserver .
RUN adduser -S -D -H -h /build webserver
USER webserver

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /build/webserver /app/
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9200
CMD ["./webserver"]
```

**main.go**:

```
func webserver(logger *log.Logger) *http.Server {
    router := http.NewServeMux()
    router.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        es, err := elasticsearch.NewDefaultClient()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error creating the client: %s", err)
        }

        res, err := es.Info()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error getting response: %s", err)
        }

        log.Println(res)
    })

    return &http.Server{
        Addr:         listenAddr,
        Handler:      router,
        ErrorLog:     logger,
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }
}
```

When I boot the server, everything is running fine and I can access Kibana and query the data that I have indexed, but as soon as I hit `localhost:8080` in Postman, the server dies and outputs:

```
web_1            | 2019/11/26 16:40:40 Error getting response: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9200: connect: connection refused
go-api_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Did you try to access the logs and verify whether its getting hit in the go server and did you try to query elastic search outside to verify whether its working ?

Comment: What I can see is the last thing I posted in the original question. `Error getting response` is dumped from webserver func in main.go, so it manages to create the `NewDefaultClient`, but cannot get `es.Info()`

Comment: Try using something like this directly , elastic.NewClient(
      elastic.SetURL("http://localhost:9200"),
      elastic.SetSniff(false),
    )

Comment: I tried that, but it seems that `SetURL` is not a func that i can use through `elasticsearch`. It refuses to compile and my IDE outputs `SetURL not declared by package elasticsearch`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 in Docker is almost always "this container".  You need to add configuration to your application (environment variables work well here) for the location of the database, and then you can use the Docker Compose service name `elasticsearch` as a host name.

Comment: @DavidMaze Do you have an example at hand, where something like this is done? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the containers and my own system, whats what, in the different files.

Answer (score -2):

You can mention the network as bridge in the docker-compose file and verify once , How it works .

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    image: go-docker-webserver
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - elastic

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.2
    environment:
      node.name: elasticsearch
      cluster.initial_master_nodes: elasticsearch
      cluster.name: docker-cluster
      bootstrap.memory_lock: "true"
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.4.2
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elastic

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

set the kernal setting to 262144 :

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: I can confirm that I get this using curl through the terminal or when I just access it directly through my browser. As mentioned in the question, I am also able to access `localhost:5601` which takes me to Kibana where I can query all the data I indexed earlier today.

Comment: Try setting the network and verify once

Comment: You do not need to explicitly declare a network; Docker Compose provides a `default` network for you.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has details.  (This also won't solve the missing address configuration in the original question.)

Comment: That's right , But there is one more aspect when you check the example in the link its specified that (Within the web container, your connection string to db would look like postgres://db:5432, and from the host machine, the connection string would look like postgres://{DOCKER_IP}:8001)

Comment: So just check docker inspect container_id and check the IP for your elasticsearch, kinbana and go webserver.

Comment: One more things that popped mind suddenly was you can directly use http://elasticsearch:9200/ to access your container when you are in the same network using docker compose try that also.

Comment: sometimes there is a a possiblity that max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low,due to that the elastic search container would have automatically stopped , So increase it using the command sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144 and then start the container again.